# Copy from one column to another (different tables same database) mysql

Tags: mysql, database

Hi I would like to copy entire contents from column Item under table IName to column Name under table Item both belonging to the same database.

I am giving the following query but it throws the error saying that the subquery returned more than one records. (There are around 600 records)

```
Insert into Item set name = (Select Item from IName)
```

Thanks

Comment: you need to add a match in your subquery (id or similar which matches the two tables by record)

Comment: The first table is totally blank. So I can't add a match

Comment: If the first table is totally empty, then maybe a SELECT INTO would work.

Comment: I just want the entire thing to copy. Item table is totally blank. So I can't add a match. I want the entire column of Iname to copy to name of table Item.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Item (Name)
  SELECT Item 
  FROM IName
```

---

When you want to insert into a single-column* table, `INSERT` works either with:

```
INSERT INTO table (column)
  VALUES (value1),(value2), ... (valueN) ;
```

or with:

```
INSERT INTO table (column)
  SELECT a_column 
  FROM a_table
                       --- optional (multiple) JOINs
                       --- and WHERE
                       --- and GROUP BY      
                       --- any complex SELECT query
```

(*OK, the above can work with a multiple-column table, too, as long as all the other - not explicitely stated in the INSERT statement - columns have been defined with a `DEFAULT` value or with `AUTO_INCREMENT`.*)

---

The `INSERT ... SET` syntax is valid in MySQL only and can be used only when you want to insert one row exactly:

```
INSERT INTO table 
  SET column = value1 ;
```

is equivalent to:

```
INSERT INTO table (column)
  VALUES (value1) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO Item (name)
SELECT Item FROM IName
```

[Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: If this isn't working, then you would likely need to share the CREATE TABLE statements to help people understand what is happening.

Comment: @Ankur Your sub query returns multiple rows for Item.

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO table_one (column1) SELECT column2 FROM table_two
```

See [MySQL Ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: You won't have much luck if you start your mysql statement with the character `Ì`.