# Unable to copy column data from one table to another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table in which each row (event) has a unique (integer) ID. I have another table, which includes the same events, and I am trying to copy the ID column from the first table to the next with no luck. I have tried creating a blank column in the second table first and I have tried it without having a blank column prepared. When I run my queries, it will spin and say that it was successfully executed, but the column in the second table is never updated.

Here is my query:

```
insert into games2 game_id
(
select games.game_id as game_id
from
games2 join games
on games2.DATE = games.DATE and
games2.HOME = games.HOME and
games2.AWAY = games.AWAY
)
```

Comment: If you're trying to update existing rows then you should be using an `UPDATE` statement, not an `INSERT`.

Comment: That makes total sense, but what about the case when I do not have a game_id column in table 2 yet? In that case the INSERT statement should create the game_id column, correct? I guess I am just confused because it will work for 10-15 seconds after I execute the query and show no errors, but it will not insert any data or even create this column. Thank you @TomH

Comment: To insert into a specific column you need to do `INSERT INTO games2 (game_id)...` (either `VALUES` or compatible `SELECT`)

Comment: At the end you want both tables to be equal?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel they both contain different data. They are concerning baseball games so they both have same dates and teams for each game, but one contains data about the game and one contains data about outside effects. I suppose I could just join them both and make a monster table but I didn't really want to.

Comment: Is (DATE, HOME, AWAY) unique? If so, you could use `INSERT SELECT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..`

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Item (Name)
  SELECT Item 
  FROM IName
```

I think this source would help you out [Copy from one column to another (different tables same database) mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526856/copy-from-one-column-to-another-different-tables-same-database-mysql)