# Insert an entire column content into another table plus a value

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Ok, I am new to SQL, so this must sound stupid. Sorry for that.

I have two tables + one junction table (many to many schema) = total of three tables.

First table

`students: student_id (PRIMARY) | name | email | password |...`

Second table

`topics: topic_id (PRIMARY) | topic_name | subject |...`

Third table (junction)

`jnct_students_topics: id (PRIMARY) | student_id_FK | topic_id_FK | done (boolean) | notes`

So how the web app would work?

Second table (`topics`) is pre-filled with all the topics students need to study.

First table (`students`) will be filled whenever a new student register for the service.

Junction table (`jnct_students_topics`) will also be filled when student registers, but (HERE COMES THE QUESTION) I need to know how to insert all topics ids + this student id in `topic_id_FK` and `student_id_FK` columns.

Because when a student registers, system will create a list for him/her with all topics to study and a checkbox for each one. After student finishs with topic studying, he/she will check the box and the boolean `done` column will become true for this topic.

I learned from [this question] ([Copy from one column to another (different tables same database) mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526856/copy-from-one-column-to-another-different-tables-same-database-mysql)) that, to populate a table column with values from another table column, I could go:

```
INSERT INTO jnct_students_topics (topic_id_FK)
SELECT topic_id 
FROM topics
```

but I need to build the statement so at the same time the student_id (related to the student that is registering) is inserted (column `student_id_FK`) in all rows that are being created.

Tired of reading? Well, I don't blame you. Nor english or SQL are native languages of mine... :)

By the way, If you think that this schema is not the best, please, I would appreciate some advice.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are populating this database from an application, you would just make sure that your also update the junction table with appropriate data.  Can you clarify what the situation is?

Comment: This is the application. I am building it. I could not understand your doubt.