# Copying Selected Row From One Table To Another But Adding Random Number During Copying

Tags: php, mysql

How to copy data from one table to another table using MySQL, but having different number of columns.
I just want to add random number during copying of selected row.

I just want to copy the selected row to another table but add new code into it. I try to use the following codes below but it wont work. I try the [Copy from one column to another (different tables same database) mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526856/copy-from-one-column-to-another-different-tables-same-database-mysql) but it wont work also.

index.php

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "1234", "testng");  
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee ORDER BY id desc";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Migrate</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:900px;"> 
                <div class="table-responsive" id="employee_table">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                               <th width="25%">Name</th>  
                               <th width="35%">Address</th>  
                               <th width="10%">Gender</th>  
                               <th width="20%">Designation</th>  
                               <th width="5%">Age</th>  
                          </tr>  
                          <?php  
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                          {  
                          ?>  
                          <tr>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["address"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["gender"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["designation"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["age"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="migrate(<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>)">MIGRATE</button></td>
                          </tr>  
                          <?php  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
    function migrate(id) {

        var mte_req = id;
        $.post("migrate.php", {
            mte_req: mte_req
          },
          function(data, status) {
             //

          }
        );      
    }
 </script>
```

migrate.php

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$password = "1234"; 
$database = "testng"; 

$db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$database) or die("Could not connect to database");

if (isset($_POST['mte_req'])) {
  $migratethis=$_POST['mte_req'];

  function randomKey($length) {
    $pool = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a', 'z'));
    $key='';

    for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
      $key .= $pool[mt_rand(0, count($pool) - 1)];
    }
      return $key;
    }

    $commit_tracer=randomKey(10);

    $query="INSERT INTO new_employee (code, name,address,gender,designation,age) VALUES ('commit_tracer', SELECT name,address,gender,designation,age FROM tbl_employee  WHERE id='$migratethis')";

    if (!$result = mysqli_query($db,$query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error());
    }
  }
?>
```

DATABASE DUMP FILE

```
-- Dumping database structure for testng
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `testng` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
USE `testng`;

-- Dumping structure for table testng.new_employee
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `new_employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `designation` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- Dumping data for table testng.new_employee: 0 rows
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `new_employee` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `new_employee` ENABLE KEYS */;

-- Dumping structure for table testng.tbl_employee
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `designation` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=177 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- Dumping data for table testng.tbl_employee: 4 rows
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tbl_employee` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `tbl_employee` (`id`, `name`, `address`, `gender`, `designation`, `age`) VALUES
  (175, 'Jane Doe', 'Alabama', 'Female', 'Junior Analyst', 23),
  (176, 'John Doe', 'Connecticut', 'Male', 'Associate Software Engineer', 21),
  (174, 'Jane Ong', 'New York', 'Female', 'WebDev', 22),
  (173, 'test Run', 'Mississipi', 'Male', 'WebDev', 21);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tbl_employee` ENABLE KEYS */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

Comment: `VALUES ('commit_tracer',` is not correct, it's not the variable you created in PHP but a normal string. Try `VALUES ('".$commit_tracer.'",`

Comment: @Michel, even I change my code using that It doesn't work.